# Question about mapping reducibility

Tags: automata, regular-languages, context-free, reductions

I am working on an assignment where one of the sub questions is:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be languages. Suppose $A$ is context free and $A ≤_m B$, which means that there is a computable function $f\colon \Sigma^* \to \Sigma^*$ such that for all $w \in \Sigma^*$, $w \in A$ iff $f(w) \in B$. Is it possible that $B$ is regular?

My take on this is that since context-free languages are on a 'higher' level than regular languages this is not possible. Apparently this is not the case, but I do not understand why.
Does anyone have a good explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is computable and $B$ is any nontrivial language (that is, $B \neq \emptyset,\Sigma^*$) then $A \leq_m B$. Indeed, pick $x \in B$ and $y \notin B$, and construct a computable reduction which decides whether its input is in $A$ or not, and outputs $x$ or $y$ accordingly.

Another issue you seem to be confused about is the meaning of *context-free*. **The fact that a language is context-free doesn't preclude it from being regular.** On the contrary, *all* regular languages are context-free.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that context-free languages are at a higher level than regular ones; or, rather, are at at least as high a level, since every regular language is also context-free.

However, what you're missing is that you're being allowed to use any computable function as a reduction, which is an even higher level still! This means you can solve the problem entirely in the reduction, as [Yuval explains](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/96882/9550).